# CakePHP multi-site file system organization with shared functions

Tags: cakephp, vendors

I have a CakePHP 1.3 mutli-site installation in the server. Each site has its own folder, and they all load the CakePHP core libraries from one same place. This is how it looks like:

- [cake] (cake's core libraries)
- [sites]

  - [site 1]

    - [app]
    - [plugins]
    - [vendors]
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
  - [site 2] *(also with its own app, plugins and vendors folders)*
  - [site 3] *(also with its own app, plugins and vendors folders)*
  - *etc*

I find myself many times in the situation where I want to implement some functions that I would like to use in all of the apps, but so far I just replicate the code inside each site. I would like to be able to declare those functions in one place and be able to call them from any site. I believe **vendors** could have something to do with this, but I've been looking in the cookbook and I can't figure out how to use that in my case.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPATE**

So by looking at the vendors, it seems to me (maybe I'm wrong) that it would work in my case if the functions in those vendors files don't need to directly interact with other CakePHP classes (for example Session, Auth, etc). I'll give an example of one of the things I'm trying to do, maybe that helps to understand better what I'm trying.

Each of the sites has its own login system (using cake's **Auth**). One of the things I want to do is, when a user logs in (the login() function in UsersController is called), have there a function that does some processing with the username of the user, and then calls the **Session->flash()** function to insert there a message (the message changes depending on that processing the function makes). So this function needs to use the **User** model and the **Session** model.

Can I do this using vendors, so I declare this one function (i.e. **processLogin()**) in a vendor, and all the sites can use that function? If so, how? If not, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick them in the **vendor** folder at the same level of **cake** and **sites**, name-spaced under a name of your choice (usually the agency name or other unique identifier).

Examples on loading vendor files in CakePHP 1.3 is explained in the Cookbook here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/943/Loading-Vendor-Files

However, I’d advise upgrading to CakePHP 2, and placing your code in a sub-folder under **lib**.

Comment: 2nd that.
And with upgrading you could think about writing an application with supports them all and gets mainly filled and maintainced via database or stackable plugins ;)

Comment: thank you guys for your replies. The thing is that there are 20 sites right now, and they're all live, so re-writing all of them would take forever. Still it's something that I plan on doing in the future, but right now I have no time for that. I've also updated my question because by looking at the **vendors** stuff it might not be what I need, please read the **UPDATE** section. Thanks again!

Comment: On upgrading, you could drop the CakePHP 2.0 code in another folder in your route, and then update the sites one-by-one, setting the `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` constant to use the **cake2** folder or whatever you’ve called it when it’s upgraded/during the upgrade.

Comment: @MartinBean ok about upgrading, but in the meantime, is it possible to do what I want to do in Cake 1.3?

Comment: Not sure; it’s been a while since I’ve used 1.3. I’d imagine you’d want to create a Auth plugin that your apps could share, rather than replicating the code across apps. Remember: DRY.

Comment: @MartinBean ok, thanks for the information. So your recommendation about upgrading to cake 2, apart from the obvious reasons of being a newer version, is it also because what I want to do is easier in that version?